# Translate Recursive C Program to LEGv8 Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

Need help converting this C code into LEGv8 assembly.  (homework)

```
unsigned long long f(unsigned long long a[], int n) {
    if (n == 0) return a[n];
    return a[n] + f(a, n - 1);
}
```

I am vaguely familiar with writing basic functions in LEGv8 assembly, but the recursion aspect is throwing me off.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

As your task is to do the thing which compilers do (translate C into Assembly), you don't need to know this is recursive. The C compiler would not know either.

To decide, whether source is using recursion is IMHO NP-complete problem, just like to decide whether the code contains infinite loop, and other NP-complete tasks, so compilers don't even bother to try to evaluate such property, and they certainly can compile similar code without that information.

Although in such simple case they would probably notice, and maybe optimize for that by unrolling few calls or evaluating the thing into constant for reasonably small inputs, this one is good candidate for translating as `for` loop summing up `n` elements of array `a`, but that's again none of your business in this task.

So if only the recursion is throwing you off, then forget this is recursion, and simply compile it into assembly language as is, line by line, instruction by instruction.